# How come the first tone in the character of 边 in the word 东边 is not written?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I am reading my textbook and I notice that the the pinyin next to

**东边**

is written as

**dōng​bian**

Why is the **first tone** not present on the **bian**? The weird thing is that in my other textbook the pinyin translation of **东边** shows both the first tones present?

Can someone explain to me this, I do not remember there being a rule like this?

Comment: see grammars (reason must really have  been mentioned many times before),in fact it seems Aug30 (last Wednesday) was the last time see 要读轻声 in comment #4 of  https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/26277/can-i-omit-%e4%b9%8b-in-%e4%b9%8b%e5%90%8e-%e4%b9%8b%e5%89%8d-%e4%b9%8b%e5%86%85

Comment: pronunciation depends on meaning, 1st tone if it means the noun "East side, the East, in the East" , neutral tone, if it part of a phrase of locality meaning "to the east of" e.g.华盛顿广场东边的一个街区

Comment: One should always pronounce the 1st tone in the standard mandarin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chinese, there is the [neutral tone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Chinese_phonology#Neutral_tone) (轻声) which does not have any tone marks.

In the word 东边, the "边" can be pronounced with a neutral tone.

Comment: Is this a rule that must be followed, because in my other resources it doesn't place a neutral tone for some reason.

Comment: 边 in 东边 can be pronounced neutral, and can also be pronounced with the 1st tone. I cannot come up with a rule about when to which now. There are some syllables that must be neutral, but then I think no resource will give it a tone mark.

Answer (score 1):

东边 in online 新华字典(the most authoritative dictionary in China) is marked with **dōngbiān**. So the correct answer is "dōngbiān".

In practice, it could often be pronounced as dōngbian, but the standard mandarin should be "dōngbiān".

So, you should fill with "dōngbiān" in any types of exams.